# IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> executes action for each file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, telerik

I need to add multiple files in a single zip file, and then upload that single file containing all items of the collection. So here´s my view code:

```
 @Html.Telerik().Upload().Name("attachments").ShowFileList(true).Async(a =>
 { 
   a.Save("AddDocumentToZipFile", "Client");      
   a.Remove("Remove", "Client");
 }).Multiple(true))
```

My action:

```
public ActionResult AddDocumentToZipFile(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> attachments)
    {
        AddFile(attachments.ToList());
        return Content("");
    }

 public void AddFile(List<HttpPostedFileBase> attachments)
    {
        var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();    
        var zipFile = new ZipFile(fileName);
        foreach (var image in attachments)
        {
            zipFile.AddFile(image.FileName, string.Empty);
        }
    }
```

But when im debugging and select multiple files, even if i put IENumerable as parameter, the Action is executed for each file, and then the AddFile method creates a zipfile for each file.

How to solve this?
Thanks.

Comment: I guess it is because your files are uploaded asynchronously, generating one http request for each file. If possible, you should add the Guid generated fileName to the model passed to the View and send this fileName back from client to server as parameter along with each file. Then, you should be able to add the new file to the correct zipfile. Be aware that you may encounter concurrency issue when adding new files to the zip file. I guess you can also switch to synchronous upload

Comment: @jbl Good point, ill try using your tips.